# Swift 4 CoreLocation not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, swift4

why this code does not working? I guess it's something with didUpdateLocations overrated method? How I can correctly connect them with my labels and make them a live :)

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class MainVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var walking = false
var pause = false
var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
var startLocation: CLLocation!
var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()

@IBOutlet weak var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var longitudeLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var horizontalAccuracyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var verticalAccuracyLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var altitudeLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var speedLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    startLocation = nil

    // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // For use in foreground
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func startDistance(_ sender: UIButton) {
    startLocation = nil
    walking = true
}

@IBAction func stopDistance(_ sender: UIButton) {
    walking = false
}

@IBAction func resetDistance(_ sender: UIButton) {
    startLocation = nil
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]

    latitudeLabel.text = String(format: "%.4f",latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    longitudeLabel.text = String(format: "%.4f",latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    horizontalAccuracyLabel.text = String(format: "%.4f",latestLocation.horizontalAccuracy)
    verticalAccuracyLabel.text = String(format: "%.4f",latestLocation.verticalAccuracy)

    altitudeLabel.text = String(format: "%.4f",latestLocation.altitude)

    if walking == true {
        if startLocation == nil {
            startLocation = latestLocation as! CLLocation
            speed = locationManager.location!.speed
            speedLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f km/h", speed * 3.6)
        }

        let distanceBetween: CLLocationDistance =
            latestLocation.distance(from: startLocation)

        distanceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", distanceBetween)
    }
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading)
{
 //   capLabel.text = String(format: "%.4f",newHeading.magneticHeading)
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

}

 }
```

I also added: Location Always Usage Description in my info.plist
And i allowed Location in the Settings on my simulator too.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue. After debugging I believe that  didUpdateLocations isn't calling for some reason.

Comment: Define "not working". That's a useless description. [Edit] your question to clearly explain in what way your code is not doing what you expect. Are you getting compiler errors/warning? Is the app crashing? Any error messages? Does the code not run as expected? Is so, in what way? Be clear and specific about your issue.

Comment: Try to run the code in an actual device. Or use simulator location debug functionality.

Comment: My  UILabels won't update, as if they are not connected with didUpdateLocations method. Precisely, on the debugger, didUpdateLocations method is never called.

Comment: @DejanMalbasic Did you ever get a location prompt which I mentioned in my answer below?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari yes, thank you

Comment: I have exactly same problem. didUpdateLocations is not being called, but I have valid CLLocation that changes over the time.

Answer (score 0):

To configure always authorization in **Swift 4** for location services which I can see you have written in your code `self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`, do the following:

There is a new key **NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription** which is also required in your `info.plist`

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string> location permission text.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string> location permission text.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string> location permission text.</string>
```

Take a look in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/request_always_authorization)

> You are required to include the **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**
>   and **NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription** keys in your app's
>   Info.plist file. (If your app supports iOS 10 and earlier, the
>   **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** key is also required.) If those keys
>   are not present, authorization requests fail immediately.

So we will have a single prompt now.
[image]